# Cannot run php artisan serve

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-artisan

> Argument 2 passed to Illuminate\Routing\UrlGenerator::__construct() must be an instance of Illuminate\Http\Request, null given, called in C:\xampp\htdocs\adgostar\test-demo\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Routing\RoutingServiceProvider.php on line 62

Comment: Post your routes, or the files where you're using `url()` helper function

Answer (score 3):

I was able to reproduce this by changing

```php
'url' => env('APP_URL', 'http://localhost'),
```

to

```php
'url' => url('APP_URL'),
```

in `config/app.php`

[image]

So make sure to remove any call to `url()` helper function in your config files

Because `vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/UrlGenerator.php` constructor is set like this

```php
public function __construct(RouteCollection $routes, Request $request, $assetRoot = null)
{
    $this->routes = $routes;
    $this->assetRoot = $assetRoot;

    $this->setRequest($request);
}
```

It expects parameter 2 to be a request, and there's no request yet when the application loads and config files are read

> No helper functions should be called in config files except for `env()`, `storage_path()`, `database_path()` and `resource_path()`

Comment: i install processmaker and have this error ,where would i search to find this method and remove it ?